# bind event to a several similar dynamically created elements and run a function

Tags: jquery, onclick, bind

I have basicly two sort of dinamicalle created delete buttons. they perform the similar action but on different objects.

So I need to bind 'click' on each delete button and then (on click on the button) let it run the same function. The code I have so far is:

```
//remove the list item

jQuery("#a").on( 'click', '.remove-button', removeFromList() );
jQuery("#b").on( 'click', '.remove-button', removeFromList() );

function removeFromList() {

console.log("i'm inside the remove function");
    var name;

    if( jQuery(this).hasClass("kruiden") ){
        name = myPlantList;
        console.log(name + "i'm inside the kruiden remove function");

    } else if( jQuery(this).hasClass("recept") ){
        name = myReceptenList;
        console.log(name + "i'm inside the recepten remove function");
    }

        //define the div element which contains the item to be deleted
        var div = jQuery(this).closest(".my-list-item");
        var indexDiv = div.index();

        name.splice(indexDiv,1);
        localStorage.setItem( name, JSON.stringify(name));

        div.slideUp(2000, function(){
                if(name.length == 0){
                        ListMessage.fadeIn(1000);
                }
        $(this).remove();
        });
```

The problem is that the code is running not on click on one of the remove-button elements, but on document.ready()....

Could anyone please suggest 
1. a nice manner to bind (can that be done in one line??? a better manner probably)
2. What is going wrong with the the executing of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick code block should be something like this.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.remove-button', function(){
            removeFromList();
});

function removeFromList(){
        alert ('hi');
    }
```

And you probably have your html like this

```
<div class="remove-button">Remove Button</div>
```

==============================================

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.... that was actually quiet stupid...
the code which is working:

```
jQuery("#a, #b").on( 'click', '.remove-button', removeFromList );

function removeFromList() {

    var nameString;
    var name;

    if( jQuery(this).hasClass("kruiden") ){
        nameString = 'myPlantList';
        name = myPlantList;

    } else if( jQuery(this).hasClass("recept") ){
        nameString = 'myReceptenList';
        name = myReceptenList;
    }

        //define the div element which contains the item to be deleted
    var div = jQuery(this).closest(".my-list-item");
    var indexDiv = div.index();

    name.splice(indexDiv,1);
    localStorage.setItem( nameString, JSON.stringify(name));

    div.slideUp(2000, function(){
                if(name.length == 0){
                        ListMessage.fadeIn(1000);
                }
        $(this).remove();

    });
```

the global mistake was calling handler by removeFromList**()**, and that should be just removeFromList